# Identify set by bag 4 - lots of circular pieces

Tags: set-identification

All I have is bag 4 from one of my son's sets. He says he wasn't missing any bags and completed them all. Can someone identify which set it's from?

[image: bag 4]

[image: pieces]

Answer (score 10):

This bag is from

[75249: Resistance Y-wing Starfighter](https://brickset.com/sets/75249-1/Resistance-Y-wing-Starfighter)
[image: set # 75249]

based on the

- [Light Bluish Gray Plate, Round 4 x 4 with 2 x 2 Round Open Center](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=11833&colorID=86&in=A)
  and
- [Minifigure, Headgear Helmet SW Zorii Bliss Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=60768pb01&idColor=11#T=C&C=11)